# Arduino DateTime appears to be being treated as int no matter how I cast it

Tags: c, arduino

The problem is essentially this:

```
DateTime timenow = RTC.now();    
Serial.println(timenow.unixtime());
double unixd = timenow.unixtime()/1.234;
Serial.println(unixd,4);
```

Outputs the following:

```
//unixtime - 1460128448
//unixd  - 1183248384.0000
```

When it should output:

```
//unixtime - 1460128448
//unixd  - 1183248337.1150
```

I have tried casting the variable differently like adding (float) or (double) or whatever, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @FiddlingBits I did also try `double unixd = timenow.unixtime()/1.234f;` Unfortunately, it  outputs the same thing.

Comment: Trying changing `unixd` to a `float`: `float unixd = ...`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Thanks man. I just tried this too, unfortunately no luck.

  `float unixd = timenow.unixtime()/1.234f;`

Outputs:

`1460130626` and `1183250176.0000`

Comment: If it helps at all, within the library RTClib, unixtime is cast as a `uint32_t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number `1183248337` without a decimal requires 31 bits.

A `double`/`float` on an AVR is 32 bits. 
You are simply using a number that is too large for the type.

You could used fixed width arithmetic using `uint64_t`. Represent your number as an integer (11832483371150 instead of 1183248337.1150) then divide/subtract to extract the parts for printing.

Comment: Thanks, will try this. I thought this might be the case as I have run into similar issues when processing milliseconds in Objective C. I will test this out and get back to you.

Comment: Note: you cannot print 64bit numbers (not handled) once you have calculated your bits n pieces, cast the portions to long or int (what ever it will fit in)